# Showing set is closed under complement ($\sigma$-algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal S$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on a set $X$. Take some $E$ in $\mathcal P(X)$. I would like to show

$$\mathcal{F} = \{(G \cap E) \cup (H \cap E^{c}) \mid G \in \mathcal{S}, H \in \mathcal{S}\}$$

is closed under complement and countable union.

---

I'm having trouble showing $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under complement. If I take $A \in \mathcal{F}$, I can write $A = (G \cap E) \cup (H\cap E^{c})$. Taking a complement gives $A^{c} =(G \cap E)^{c} \cap (H^c \cap E^{c})^{c}$  which simplifies to $(G^c \cup E^c) \cap (H^c \cup E)$. I guess I can distribute and get

$$((G^{c} \cup E^{c}) \cap H^c) \cup ((G^{c} \cup E^{c}) \cap E)$$

and the left-term becomes $(G^c \cap H^c) \cup (E^{c} \cap H^c)$ but it's not in a form I can show is in the set itself. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Oh. I want to show $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra provided $\mathcal{S}$ itself is a $\sigma$-algebra. Could I use the second fact to help out here maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}((G\cap E)\cup(H\cap E^c))^c&=(G^c\cup E^c)\cap(H^c\cup E)\\
&=(G^c\cap H^c)\cup(G^c\cap E)\cup(E^c\cap H^c)\\
&=(G^c\cap E)\cup(E^c\cap H^c)
\end{align}$$
because $G^c\cap H^c$ may be split into
$G^c\cap H^c\cap E\subset G^c\cap E$ and $G^c\cap H^c\cap E^c\subset E^c\cap H^c.$

Answer (score 0):

$(G^c \cup E^c) \cap (H^c \cup E))=[E\cap (G^{c})]\cup [E^{c} \cap H^{c}]$.